# Discord.py NameError: name 'updatedata' is not defined

Tags: python, database, firebase-realtime-database, discord.py

Hello I am trying to make a discord.py bot that counts the total members and send it to firebase real-time database I have connected real-time database and I want to update the "totalUsers": in data{} but I am getting this error
I am doing update data(" totalUsers") but it's not working if I'm doing anything wrong pls help

```
File "filename.py", line 53, in get_users
2021-03-01T13:54:37.146957+00:00 app[worker.1]:     updatedata('totalUsers')
2021-03-01T13:54:37.146958+00:00 app[worker.1]: NameError: name 'updatedata' is not defined
```

Code

```
import discord
import time
import io
import json
import os
import sys
import pyrebase

firebaseConfig={
  "apiKey": "AIzaSyA5I9yq34ZG2tcOn5sF0liUl3AT-5IEo1I",
  "authDomain": "organic-pe-form.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://organic-pe-form-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  "projectId": "organic-pe-form",
  "storageBucket": "organic-pe-form.appspot.com",
  "messagingSenderId": "110093275502",
  "appId": "1:110093275502:web:906f98718458757271f17f",
  "measurementId": "G-FKNDYN6RC2"
}

firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)

db=firebase.database()

data={'totalUsers':""}
db.push(data)



client = discord.Client()

def setup():
    client.loop.create_task(get_users())
    client.run(os.getenv('Token'))

async def get_users():

    online = 0
    idle = 0
    offline = 0

    await client.wait_until_ready()
    startTime = time.time()
    while not client.is_closed:
        for server in client.servers:
            for member in server.members:
                if str(member.status) == 'online':
                    online += 1
                elif str(member.status) == 'idle':
                    idle += 1
        await client.close()

    totalUsers = online + idle
    updatedata('totalUsers')


def returnCount(total):
    print('Total is {}'.format(str(total)))
    updateJson('user.json', total)
    return str(total)
    
    
def updateJson(path, new_id):
    newPath = ensureAbsPath(path)
    with open(newPath, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f) # Load json data into the buffer

    tmp = data['users']
    data['users'] = new_id

    with open(newPath, 'w+') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(data)) # Write the new user count to the cache
    
    
def ensureAbsPath(path):
    botRootDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])) + '/'
    return path if os.path.isabs(path) else botRootDir + path

setup()
```

Comment: No function `updatedata` is defined in the code you shared, and it's also not defined in the `pyrebase` library that you use. Where do you expect this function to come from?

Comment: Idk how do I do it

Comment: Good job leaking your firebase creds

Comment: There are my test project